# Composite Type error in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

A WCF newbie asking for help.  What I’m doing wrong here:
ICardService

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://xxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx/xx/xxxxxx")]
interface ICardService
{
     [OperationContract]
     Coupon CreateCouponCard(string cardDefinitionCode);
}
```

---

```
public class CardService : ICardService
    {
        public Coupon CreateCouponCard(string cardDefinitionCode)
        {
            Coupon composite = new Coupon();

            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.PassTypeIdentifier="sdfsdf";
                composite.Icon.DisplayGroup = "czxczxczx";
            }
            return composite;
        }
    }
```

---

```
 [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class Coupon : CardCommonDefinition
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string Description {get; set;}

[DataMember]
public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

}
```

---

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class CardCommonDefinition
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string PassTypeIdentifier {get; set;}
  [DataMember]
        public CardFieldDefinitionEntity Icon {get; set;}
     }
```

---

```
  [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class CardFieldDefinitionEntity
    {

        [DataMember]
        public string DisplayGroup {get; set;}
}
```

---

When I run this it is failing at the composite.Icon.DisplayGroup = "czxczxczx"; with an object not set to an instance of an object.

I don’t have any clue who to resolved it, can you please help me?

Comment: You need to make sure that the Icon property of Coupon object is initialized before you set `DisplayGroup` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by two way.

One- Initialize `Icon` property before using it.

```
public Coupon CreateCouponCard(string cardDefinitionCode)
{

    Coupon composite = new Coupon();
    if (composite == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
    }
    if (composite.BoolValue)
    {
        composite.PassTypeIdentifier="sdfsdf";
        composite.Icon = new CardFieldDefinitionEntity();
        composite.Icon.DisplayGroup = "czxczxczx";
    }
    return composite;
}
```

Two - Have a constructor of `CardCommonDefinition` and initialize `Icon` property in it so that you don't need to worry about it being null.

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class CardCommonDefinition
{
    public CardCommonDefinition()
    {
        this.Icon = new CardFieldDefinitionEntity();
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string PassTypeIdentifier {get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public CardFieldDefinitionEntity Icon {get; set;}
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Coupon : CardCommonDefinition
{
    public Coupon : base()
    { }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description {get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public bool BoolValue
    {
        get { return boolValue; }
        set { boolValue = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this approach really the best way to design the service? Basically, I'm receiving from the DB a CardDefinitonEntity with all the fields necessary to create any type of card.  What I want to do is to have a class for each type of card (coupon, event, membership, store, etc) with those fields specific to those cards and a base class with the common fields for all the card types.  But I'm not sure if the approach I used is really the correct one since it seems a little bit awkward to instantiate a property before used it.  Im new to C# so maybe that is why it seems akward to me.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you instantiate it but you must instantiate before you can use an object. Else you surely will get NullReferenceException. The approach is suggested based on the details you provided in the question. There is no mention of database or other classes. You need to provide relevant information if you want to get the best fitting solution.